# How to detect exact length in regex

Tags: regex

I have two regular expressions that validate the values entered.

One that allows any length of Alpha-Numeric value:

```
@"^\s*(?<ALPHA>[A-Z0-9]+)\s*"
```

And the other only allows numerical values:

```
@"^\s*(?<NUM>[0-9]{10})"
```

How can I get a numerical string of the length of 11 not to be catched by the `NUM` regex.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think what you're trying to say is that you don't want to allow any more than 10 digits. So, just add a `$` at the end to specify the end of the regex.

Example: `@"^\s*(?[0-9]{10})$"`

---

Here's my original answer, but I think I read you too exact.

```
string myRegexString = `@"(?!(^\d{11}$)` ... your regex here ... )";
```

That reads "while ahead is not, start, 11 digits, end"

Answer (score 5):

If it's single line, you could specify that your match must happen at the end of the line, like this in .net ...

```
^\s*([0-9]{10})\z
```

That will accept 1234567890 but reject 12345678901.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to match *up to* 10 digits?  Try this:

```
@"^\s*[0-9]{1,10}\s*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match only numbers that are 10 digits long, just add a trailing anchor using $, like this:

```
^\s*(?:[0-9]{10})\s*$
```

That will match any number that is exactly 10 digits long (with optional space on either side).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var pattern =/\b[0-9]{10}$\b/;

// the b modifier is used for boundary and $ is used for exact length
```

Answer (score 0):

Match something non-numeric after the length 10 string. My regex-foo isn't that good, but I think you've got it setup there to catch a numeric string of exactly length 10, but since you don't match anything after that, a length 11 string would also match. Try matching beyond the end of the number and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

You could try alternation?

```
^\s*(?\d{1,10}|\d{12,})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should match only 10 digits and allow arbitrary numbers of whitespaces before and after the digits.

Non-capturing version: (only matches, the matched digits are not stored)

```
^\s*(?:\d{10})\s*$
```

Capturing version: (the matched digits are available in subgroup 1, as $1 or \1)

```
^\s*(\d{10})\s*$
```