# issue with mobile validation in cake php

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

1.Need 10 digit mobile No(working)

2.Can be start 0-9(working)

**3.not more then 10 digit(not working->that required not working it's take also more than 10 digit like exp 11, 12 digit and more also )**

for that i have implement that rule

```
'mobile_no' =>array(
'rule'=>array('custom','/([0-9]{1}[0-9]{9})/'),
'allowEmpty'=>false, 
'message'=>'Invalid mobile number! mobile number format: eg 0755434434'
 ),
```

so i want to know where is problem in my code related to 3rd point

thanks in adv

Comment: You have not included start & end of string i.e. `^` & `$` respectively in your regex...Please check my answer for detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your regex says "match anything that contains a 10-digit phone number", however, what you really want is "match any string with 10 characters that is a phone number".

The following regex should fix the issue: `/^([0-9]{1}[0-9]{9})$/`

Answer (score 1):

Use [maxLength](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1168/maxLength) validation

Also check this [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787354/how-to-detect-exact-length-in-regex).

Try `^\d{10}$`

Comment: thanks for replay, but sir i want to know wht's problem in my code

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not correct. Try:

```
([0]{1}[0-9]{9})(?=\W)
```