# Partly exact matching using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to find if a **String** starts with "abcd" followed by 1-5 digits, then a comma, then ends with 0-3 digits.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("abcd[0-9]{1,5},[0-9]{0,3}$");

    String[] data = { "pqrsabcd12345,5", "abcd1234,5", "abcd1234542155,",
            "abcdSD12345,555", "abcd123,555", "abcd12,5555",
            "abcd,5555ffdfd", "abcd2,5555ffdfd", "abcd2,5" };
    for (CharSequence input : data) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.format("\nI found the text  %s :"
                    + " \"%s\" starting at "
                    + "index %d and ending at index %d.%n", input,
                    matcher.group(), matcher.start(), matcher.end());
        }
    }
```

The output :

```
I found the text  pqrsabcd12345,5 : "abcd12345,5" starting at index 4 and ending at index 15.

I found the text  abcd1234,5 : "abcd1234,5" starting at index 0 and ending at index 10.

I found the text  abcd123,555 : "abcd123,555" starting at index 0 and ending at index 11.

I found the text  abcd2,5 : "abcd2,5" starting at index 0 and ending at index 7.
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787354/how-to-detect-exact-length-in-regex), I could ensure the ends with part. I think I am left with stopping Strings like `"pqrsabcd12345,5"`

Please let me know if I have missed something.

Comment: What problems are you having with your current regex again?

Comment: Really can't understand your issue. What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't want "pqrsabcd12345,5" in the output as it does not start with "abcd"

Comment: If the string must start with "abcd" then you need to put the ^ symbol at the start of the pattern, so `"^abcd[0-9]{1,5},[0-9]{0,3}$"` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a little modification to your regex: -

```
"^abcd[0-9]{1,5},[0-9]{0,3}$"
```

You forgot to use *Caret* - `^` to ensure that the pattern is matched at the start of your string.

Alternatively, you can also use `Matcher#matches()` instead of `Matcher#find()` method, if you want your pattern to match at the ends. That way you won't need to use `anchors`.

So, the difference between `matches()` and `find()` can be easily shown with your string that is not satisfying your requirement: -

```
// pattern is the reference you are having
pattern.matcher("pqrsabcd12345,5").find(); // Will return true
pattern.matcher("pqrsabcd12345,5").matches(); // Will return false
```

Comment: @labbhattacharjee.. With `matches()` you need none of them. Both the anchors are implicit with it.